# Vivado VHDL width mismatch - how can I fix it?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

Please consider this very simple minimal reproducible code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity test is
    generic ( LENGTH : integer range 1 to 16 := 5 );

    Port ( x : in STD_LOGIC;
           y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
           );
end test;
architecture Behavioral of test is
                
        signal a : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
        signal b : std_logic_vector (LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
                
        signal i : integer range 0 to LENGTH-1 := 1;
    
begin
    y <= a;

process
    begin 
    
        if i = LENGTH then
            i <= 1;
        else
            a <= a(15 downto i + 1) & b(i downto 0); 
        end if; 
        
        i <= i + 1;
        
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

My need is to join some elements of `b` into `a`, depending on `i`. By running the RTL on Vivado, it says:

```
[Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 16 bits, source has 20 bits
```

I don't really get why. Anyhow, the overall range will be `15 - (i + 1) + (i - 0) = 15 ... 0` and fits in the 16 bits of `output` -- what's the deal for 20 bits?

I should say the problem vanishes (obviously) if I use plain constants instead of `i`, but I still don't get what's going on.

Comment: Variable bit slicing with vivado has always been broken. You're likey need to make a case statement on i and enter each case with constants.

Comment: @Tricky: oh that'd be a pity, cause actually `i` is a generic and I'd have to specify possibly 15 combinations as well just for that. So it's strictly a Vivado issue? Could you tell me whether this can be implemented differently yet achieving the same functionality?

Comment: This isn't a [mcve], there's no entity declaration, no context clause nor is `i` a generic constant. There's no There are 12 values where integer `i` with a range of 0 to 15 is not a valid index of `b` in expression `b(i downto 0)`. If `i` While with a generic constant you could restrict it's range to that of `b` and the indexes of the `a` and `b` slices would be globally static and wouldn't cause a synthesis problem.  Your "*minimal reproducible code*" and your comment "*`i` is a generic*" are at odds.

Comment: @newuser if `i` really were a generic then there wouldnt be a problem.

Comment: @newuser 20 is because `a` is 16 bits wide and `b` is 4 bits wide. Vivado doesn't have the code analysis to know that both parts of your assignment won't be larger than the total based on `i` so it looks like it assumes the largest size and caters for that.

Comment: @user1155120: I've added some further code to get it entirely MCVE. Hope it's better now.

Comment: @PaulieTree: I reckon that could be possible, however I'm not contatenating `a&b` directly rather some slices of them. Still it looks like Vivado plays it safe and just ignores that -- any way to sort it out? I'm not very skilled with VHDL.

Comment: @newuser your code still is not an MCVE. The process is missing a sensitivity list or wait statements.

Comment: `i <= i + 1;` besides type integer `i` not rolling over it won't simulate nor synthesize to anything useful with `i` in the missing sensitivity list (`i` is a best a gated oscillator). This assignment should occur on a clock edge. The assignment to `a` as is could be a striking oscillator for some values of `b` and `a` should any elements of `a` have the ability to be assigned different binary values. Provide a useful [mcve]. (I see my earlier comment lost the bit about the sensitivity list Tricky mentions).

Answer (score 0):

For runtime variable I (as per the question)...

instead of a big CASE, you can use the value of I to generate masks, and evaluate `(A and MASKA) or (B and MASKB)`. Which is equivalent to the multiplexer the synthesis tool would generate if it wasn't broken.

For generic I (it's not fair to move the goalposts in the comments!)

this approach generates unnecessary hardware, which will be optimised out by any competent synthesis tool.

(There are of course other problems with this code; I assume you deleted the clock, taking the MCVE notion a bit too far. You should leave it valid synthesisable code)

Comment: An answer or a comment, Brian?

Comment: @user1155120 , started as one, grew into the other. My gut feel is the OP mostly knows what he's doing and doesn't need a fully worked out solution, but got thrown off track by a tool bug. Feel free to downvote or add an answer if you disagree.

Comment: a(15 downto i + 1) is always 'U's. Lacking a [mcve] it doesn't demonstrate a practical problem or a solution to future readers. LENGTH is the generic not i without which you'd need masks for every slice length. The historic IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn, 8.3.2.1 Array types, requiring static discrete ranges) solution would be `for n = 0 to LENGTH - 1 loop if n = i then a <= a(15 downto n + 1) & b(n downto 0); end if; end loop;` where n is a constant within the loop sequence of statements describing a multiplexer with a LENGTH number of inputs (and subject to minimization).